# gradle ignoreFailures test property

Tags: java, gradle, junit

My `build.gradle` file is like the following :

```
apply plugin: "java"
...
test {
  ...
  ignoreFailures = "$ignoreFailureProp"
}
```

and a `gradle.properties` with

```
ignoreFailureProp=false
```

When executed `gradle clean build`, the unit test failures do not mark the build as failed.

I know the default behaviour is to fail the build, but I want to explicitly set it through a property, to change in without modifying the build file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `ignoreFailureProp` property is a string so the `ignoreFailures` (which should be a boolean) is set as a string and therefore will always be true.

You could do this instead:

```
apply plugin: "java"

test {
    ignoreFailures = ignoreFailureProp.toBoolean()
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 10):

You do not have to use a file like `gradle.properties`.

If you change your `build.gradle` to:

```
apply plugin: "java"
...
test {
  ...
  ignoreFailures Boolean.getBoolean("test.ignoreFailures")
}
```

and invoke the tests with `gradle -Dtest.ignoreFailures=true clean build` you are done **without editing any file**. Note that, if you do not set the parameter or set it to any other value than `true` (case in-sensitive) failures are not ignored (ie. the default behaviour).

Comment: Groovy is weird.  This should be fine.

Comment: An equal sign is **optional** but not needed: `ignoreFailures = Boolean.getBoolean("test.ignoreFailures")`